# Lorentz transform of spin particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, quantum-spin

Let's say that I see a particle (i.e. an electron) is moving along the y-axis and has a spin of -1/2 along the z-direction.

Now, if another person who is moving with certain velocity v along the y-direction, how will that person observe the spin of the particle? Will it become a combination of the projections in (x,y,z)? Or will it stay the same?

If we want to be more explicit, let's assume the initial state of the particle, as observed from rest is $|p=p_2,s_z=-1/2 \rangle$ and $\Lambda$ is the Lorentz transform.

Comment: Read Peskin’s intro on the unitary realization of the Lorentz group on Fock space in his QFT book